# Sails.js / Waterline .add() and .remove() only works on second call

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to use a Many-to-Many association between 2 models and I have to call .add() or .remove() twice for it to work properly:

```
// User.js Model
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    connections: {
      collection: 'connection',
      via: 'users'
    }
  }
}

// Connection.js Model
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    users: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'connections'
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code I have in my UsersController.js:

```
    User.findById(req.params.user)
    .populate('connections')
    .exec(function(err, users) {
      if (err) return res.status(404).end(); // Not really a 404 but good for now

      var user = users[0];
      user.connections.add(req.body.connection_id);
      user.save(function(err) {
        // In my tests err is null/undefined
        return res.status(204).end();
      }
    });
```

I get a 204 back with no errors in the log or nothing else failed. When I check in my MongoDB database, the user's connections field is just an empty array. If I send the same request again, then I get a an error saying the connection_id already exists for that user. I look into the database, and now the connection appears in the user's connections field. It does the same thing when I remove a connection, I have to send it twice for it to take effect. Anyone have any ideas?

Here are the module versions I'm using:

- Node.js version: 0.12.0
- Sails.js version: 0.11.0
- sails-mongo version: 0.10.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like something related to synchronous vs asynchronous methods... meaning you are exiting the method before a certain request is completed. However not sure where that is happening. See if this helps:

```
var connectionId = req.param('connection_id');
var userId = req.param('user');

User.find(userId)
.populate('connections')
.exec(function(err, users) {
  if (err) return res.status(404).end(); // Not really a 404 but good for now

//BTW might be good to double check doing console.log("users: "+JSON.stringify(users));

  var user = users[0];
  user.connections.push(connectionId);

//Is it really there? console.log("user: "+JSON.stringify(user));

  user.save(function(err) {
    // In my tests err is null/undefined
    return res.status(204).end();
  }
});
```